# How can I create a list of dataframes and get them back by calling a key value

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a for loop like this:

```
tracks = [1010, 2020]

df_list = []
for i in tracks:
    query = ''' quer_here '''
    df = pd.read_sql(query, con=con)
    to_dict = df.to_dict()
    df_list.append(to_dict)
```

So i am running a query, reading it as pandas dataframe then the dataframe to dict and append this dict to a list.

From here I can get the dataframe back calling, for example:

```
pd.DataFrame(df_list[0])
```

What I want to do from here is to append every dict with a key that is the `i` value  so I can get the dataframe back calling:

```
pd.DataFrame(df_list[1010])
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame(df_list[2020])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not `df=pd.read_sql(query, con=con); df_dict[i] = df`, where `df_dict` is initialized to an empty dict?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array in python with arbitrary index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719962/array-in-python-with-arbitrary-index)

Comment: nope.  Dosen't work. I'll stick to the initial code and call `pd.DataFrame(df_list[0])`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to convert the dataframe created by each SQL query to a dictionnary and after that, using [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor to do a *rollback* ?

IMO, you can simply use :

```
tracks = [1010, 2020]

df_dict = {}
for i in tracks:
    query = ''' quer_here '''
    df_dict[i] = pd.read_sql(query, con=con)
```

*NB: This will create a dictionnary with tracks as keys and dataframes as values. You can access each dataframe by using key-based indexing : `df_dict[1010], df_dict[2020]`.*